# Sort objects in Java without 'proper' compareTo method

Tags: java

We need a *compareTo* method that works with object that are of different classes and guarantees it will never returns 0 if the objects are not the same.

```
 Integer.compare(System.identityHashCode(o1), System.identityHashCode(o2))
```

Is not working as *[System.identityHashCode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#identityHashCode%28java.lang.Object%29)* in Java does not guarantee two different objects will return a different identityHashCode (yes, yes it happens).

Some ideas ?

Comment: What exactly does `not the same` mean here? Can't you check references with `==`?

Comment: How do you know when an object is bigger than other if the class is totally different?

Comment: Objects of different classes? Explain it, please: Does that mean that `o1` and `o2` could be of different classes in the same invocation to `compareTo`?

Comment: Pablo, yes this is the problem :-), but it can be anything that is not random. the notion of order doesn't imply bigger

Comment: Santi, let's say we can not implement a proper compareTo method in o1. Just o1 and o2 are objects of two different classes

Comment: If `o1` and `o2` are different instances the hashcode should be different. Citation from JavaDoc on `Object.hashCode()`. "As much as is reasonably practical, the hashCode method defined by class Object does return distinct integers for distinct objects.  (This is typically implemented by converting the _internal address of the object into an integer_, but this implementation technique is not required by the JavaTM programming language.)" - True it says that doing it that way is not required but on most platforms that should be " reasonably practical".

Comment: Do you need to sort them using compareTo or just say if they are same/different? You can't provide symmetric rule for random objects.

Comment: @Pablo you can do that by just operating on `Object` and using the identity hashcode as the OP does, the question would be: other than  _some_ fixed order what good does that do? What does one use that "order" for?

Comment: This is for ordefing of lock acquisition?

Comment: @Thomas System.identityHashCode(o1) is randomly generated so in collection of 64K objects you have a high chance that they will conflict.

Comment: @PeterLawrey yes you're right, it's random in the sense that we don't know how the memory address is determined and since memory addresses don't fit into integers anymore that might result in conflicts. Maybe it's time to increase the hashCode to longs or provide an alternative method that produces more accurate results.

Comment: I thought the `==` operator would work here ... what am I missing?

Comment: @Thomas The System.identityHashCode() doesn't have anything to do with the object's address, otherwise the object couldn't be moved as it would change the hashCode().  It is stored in the object header, see my answer when I use Unsafe to overwrite it. o_O

Comment: @dave it does, but if `a != b` is `a > b` or `a < b`

Comment: @PeterLawrey Thanks.  I'm curious now what is the default behavior `a > b` and `a < b` for Objects

Comment: @dave there is no defined behaviour which is where this question arises. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no sure what to do this as different objects can have both the same System.identityHashCode() and hashCode(). You can create two objects at will with are the same for both of these using Unsafe, and randomly if you create enough.

```
public class UnsafeIdentityDemo {

    static final Unsafe UNSAFE;

    static {
        try {
            Field theUnsafe = Unsafe.class.getDeclaredField("theUnsafe");
            theUnsafe.setAccessible(true);
            UNSAFE = (Unsafe) theUnsafe.get(null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AssertionError(e);
        }
    }

    public static void setIdentityHashCode(Object o, int code) {
        UNSAFE.putInt(o, 1l, code & 0x7FFF_FFF);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Double d = 1.0;
        Double d2 = 1.0;
        setIdentityHashCode(d, 1);
        setIdentityHashCode(d2, 1);
        System.out.println("d: "+d+" System.identityHashCode(d): "+System.identityHashCode(d));
        System.out.println("d2: "+d2+" System.identityHashCode(d2): "+System.identityHashCode(d2));
        System.out.println("d == d2: " + (d == d2));
    }
}
```

prints

```
d: 1.0 System.identityHashCode(d): 1
d2: 1.0 System.identityHashCode(d2): 1
d == d2: false
```

What you could do is assign the objects based on the order they are discovered (IntelliJ's debugger does this)

```
public class UniversalComparator implements Comparator<Object> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        if (o1 == o2)
            return 0;
        int cmp = compare(o1.getClass(), o2.getClass());
        // if the classes are the same, and they are Comparable.
        if (cmp == 0 && o1 instanceof Comparable)
            cmp = ((Comparable) o1).compareTo(o2);
        // otherwise use the built in toString/hashCode/identityHashCode
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = Integer.compare(o1.toString(), o2.toString());
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = Integer.compare(o1.hashCode(), o2.hashCode());
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = Integer.compare(System.identityHashCode(o1), System.identityHashCode(o2));
        // otherwise generate a unique id for them
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = Integer.compare(uniqueId(o1), uniqueId(o2));
        return cmp;
    }

    final Map<Object, Integer>  uniqueId = new IdentityHashMap<>();
    private synchronized int uniqueId(Object o) {
        return uniqueId.computeIfAbsent(o, k -> uniqueId.size());
    }
}
```

This will ensure that all object of different types will be

- sorted by class name first.
- if the same class and `Comparable` use the built in compare.
- otherwise if the same class, compare by `toString()`, then `hashCode()`, then `System.identityHashCode`
- otherwise generate a unique id.

this means for most objects you will get a predictable sort order.

Note: this will slowly build up a map of all the conflicting objects.  It will be small but is a potential source of memory leak. A `WeakIdentityHashMap` would be better.

Comment: One could also use the class' hash code to reduce probability of collisions before getting the unique id. That would further reduce the risk of a memory leak.

Comment: Just to clarify: I didn't mean `o1.hashCode()` (that might help as well though) but rather `o1.getClass().hashCode()` since the objects might be of different classes as the OP states.

Comment: @Thomas You could, although I would compare the class names.

Comment: Hmm, what would be the advantage of that? The better defined hash code?

Comment: @Thomas if you used names, you would have an idea of what order two objects of classes would be.  Though it it hardly makes a difference.

Comment: @Thomas Your suggestion gave me an idea on how to make the sort order for most objects predictable.